# Is it good practice to use ToString() to convert a number directly to a string?

Tags: c#, tostring

Is it good practice to convert a number to a string directly using `ToString()`? Like this:

```
string numStr = 0.ToString();
```

Or should the number be entered into an int variable first and then use `ToString()` on that? Like this:

```
int num = 0;
string numStr = num.ToString();
```

Comment: Can't you just enter `"0"`, instead of casting int to string?

Comment: Side note: `0.ToString();` as well as `num.ToString()` is *culture specific* (it uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`), in some (very special for just `0`) cases you can have *unexpected* results

Comment: If you are using 
int num = 0;
string numStr = num.ToString();
then use 
Convert.ToString(num)

Comment: @Shocky That's almost always OK for `0`, but for a floating point number then `0.1.ToString()` != `"0.1"` for, say, the German locale. So you have to be careful just putting string representations of numbers into code rather than using `ToString()` (or equivalent).

Comment: The IL versions of both fragments are basically identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a Good practice to store your numbers in a *Variable* and then using the `ToString()` ***See example at the end***

*ToString()* accepts an over load like `ToString(IFormatProvider provider)` where you can specify culture-specific format information

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

The *Alternative* to *ToString()* is to use *Convert.ToString(Int value)* the difference is that *Convert* also handles *null* values

```
var str = Convert.ToString(value);
var str1 = Convert.ToString(value,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> Is it good practice to convert a number to a string directly using
>   ToString()? Like this:
>
> *Example*
>
> ```
> 1.ToString(); // Compiles fine
> -1.ToString(); // Compile error, note you can surround it with parenthesis to get it to compile
> ```

Answer (score 0):

when you say "string a = 0.ToString();"
----------------------^-----here you are already declaring that its a string so saying .ToString(); is redundant